# Infinite Scroll of Ag Grid not working when using Api

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to implement Infinite Scroll without Pagination from the below code in `Angular Core 6.1.0` and `ag-grid - ^17.1.1` and `ag-grid-angular - 17.1.0`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-infinite-scroll-example

The example works fine. But when I introduce Api to get data from the Database, I am getting empty records in the Front-End Grid

I have changed the onGridReady method as below

```
onGridReady(params: any) {
    console.log("onGridReady");
    this.clearAgGrid();

    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.gridColumnApi;

    var dataSource: IDatasource = {
      getRows: (params: IGetRowsParams) => {
        this.userService.GetUserDetails(this.loginUserId).subscribe(data => {
          this.rowData = data;
          params.successCallback(data, 1000);
        })
      }
    }
    this.gridOptions.rowModelType = 'infinite';
    this.gridOptions.dataSource = dataSource;
    params.api.setDataSource(this.rowData);
}

clearAgGrid() {
    let self = this;
    let dataSource = {
      getRows(params: any) {
        params.successCallback([], 0);
      }
    };
    this.gridOptions.api.setDatasource(dataSource);
}

this.gridOptions = {
  rowSelection: 'single',
  cacheBlockSize: 100,
  maxBlocksInCache: 2,
  enableServerSideFilter: false,
  enableServerSideSorting: true,
  rowModelType: 'infinite',
  pagination: false,
  paginationAutoPageSize: true
};
```

The code in the `html` file is as below

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 100%" class="ag-theme-balham"
                [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
                [rowData]="rowData"
                (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
                #grid
></ag-grid-angular>
```

Column Definitions as below

```
this.columnDefs = [
  { field: 'UserName' },
  { field: 'EmailId' },
  { field: 'MobileNo' },
  { field: 'Address' },
  { field: 'IsActive' }
];
```

The API is defined as below

```
public GetUserDetails(userId: string): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.httpClient.put<User[]>(this.uriBase + '/GetUserDetails/' + userId, { headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' } }).pipe(share());
}
```

Even though data is coming in other scenario, the same data is not appearing in the Front-End Infinite Grid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your onGridReady method you should call setDatasource with a datasource object, not with row data.
So the modified version of the method would look like the following:

```
  onGridReady(params: any) {
    console.log("onGridReady");
    this.clearAgGrid();
                
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.gridColumnApi;
                
    var dataSource: IDatasource = {
      getRows: (params: IGetRowsParams) => {
        this.userService.GetUserDetails(this.loginUserId).subscribe(data => {
          // no need to provide row data actually. You can omit this line
          this.rowData = data; 
          params.successCallback(data, 1000);
        })
      }
    }
    this.gridOptions.rowModelType = 'infinite';
    // no need for this line either
    this.gridOptions.dataSource = dataSource; 
    // pass the dataSource object instead of the row data
    params.api.setDatasource(dataSource); 
  }
```

Reference: [Angular Data Grid: Infinite Row Model](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/infinite-scrolling/#turning-on-infinite-scrolling)